# Error in storm list when upgrade storm to 1.2.3

Tags: java, upgrade, apache-storm

In storm.yaml (version 1.0.0), I have the next configuration:

`nimbus.host: "%nimbus%"`

When upgrade version, I change to:

`nimbus.seeds: ["%nimbus%"]`

In my script to deploy all topologies, I check the storm list with next command (in version 1.0.0):

`storm list -c nimbus.host=localhost`

I got the next error:

```
Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options=nimbus.host%3Dlocalhost -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/storm-1.2.3 -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/share/storm-1.2.3/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/lib/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/extlib/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/extlib-daemon/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/conf:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/bin org.apache.storm.command.list
2952 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Using deprecated config nimbus.host for backward compatibility. Please update your storm.yaml so it only has config nimbus.seeds
3033 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getLeader
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getLeader(Nimbus.java:1166) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getLeader(Nimbus.java:1154) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:93) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:66) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.storm.command.list$_main.invoke(list.clj:22) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.command.list.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:66)
    at org.apache.storm.command.list$_main.invoke(list.clj:22)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at org.apache.storm.command.list.main(Unknown Source)
```

When upgrade version, I change the command  to:

`storm list -c nimbus.seeds=[localhost]`

But, I got the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12317.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field NIMBUS_SEEDS must be an Iterable but was a class java.lang.String
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$2.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:125)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$NestableFieldValidator.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:304)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:299)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:707)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:742)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:721)
    at org.apache.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:74)
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:79)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__975.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12317.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field NIMBUS_SEEDS must be an Iterable but was a class java.lang.String
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$2.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:125)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$NestableFieldValidator.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:304)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:299)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:707)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:742)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:721)
    at org.apache.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:74)
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:79)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__975.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options=nimbus.seeds%3D%5Blocalhost%5D -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/storm-1.2.3 -Dstorm.log.dir= -Djava.library.path= -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/share/storm-1.2.3/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/lib/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/extlib/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/extlib-daemon/*:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/conf:/usr/share/storm-1.2.3/bin org.apache.storm.command.list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field NIMBUS_SEEDS must be an Iterable but was a class java.lang.String
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$2.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:125)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidationUtils$NestableFieldValidator.validateField(ConfigValidationUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:304)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$ListEntryTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:299)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:707)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:742)
    at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:721)
    at org.apache.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:74)
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:79)
    at org.apache.storm.command.list$_main.invoke(list.clj:22)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at org.apache.storm.command.list.main(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me with this error? Thank you.

**Attach**:

config file in 1.0.0 version

```
storm.local.hostname: "%local.ip%"

storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "%zookeeper%"

nimbus.host: "%nimbus%"

# netty transport
storm.messaging.transport: "org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context"
storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 16384
storm.messaging.netty.max_retries: 10
storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms: 1000
storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms: 5000

drpc.servers:
  - "%nimbus%"
drpc.port: 3772
drpc.invocations.port: 3773

### supervisor.* configs are for node supervisors
# Define the amount of workers that can be run on this machine. Each worker is assigned a port to use for communication
supervisor.slots.ports:    
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
    - 6704
    - 6705
    - 6706
    - 6707
    - 6708
    - 6709
    - 6710
    - 6711
    - 6712
    - 6713
    - 6714
    - 6715
    - 6716    
    - 6717    
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
#how long supervisor will wait to ensure that a worker process is started
supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs: 120
#how long between heartbeats until supervisor considers that worker dead and tries to restart it
supervisor.worker.timeout.secs: 30
#how frequently the supervisor checks on the status of the processes it's monitoring and restarts if necessary
supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs: 3
#how frequently the supervisor heartbeats to the cluster state (for nimbus)
supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 5
supervisor.enable: true
supervisor.cpu.capacity: 200.0
supervisor.memory.capacity.mb: 4096.0

### worker.* configs are for task workers
worker.heap.memory.mb: 1024
worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:artifacts/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"
worker.gc.childopts: ""

### check https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml for compelte defaults
```

Error in logs/nimbus.log

> 2019-11-20 17:30:07.158 o.a.s.t.ProcessFunction pool-14-thread-8
>   [ERROR] Internal error processing getLeader
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: No nimbus leader participant host found,
>   have you started your nimbus hosts?   at
>   org.apache.storm.zookeeper$to_NimbusInfo.invoke(zookeeper.clj:241)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.zookeeper$zk_leader_elector$reify__2212.getLeader(zookeeper.clj:294)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
>   ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]    at
>   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:313)
>   ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_reified_nimbus$reify__9284.getLeader(nimbus.clj:2428)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Processor$getLeader.getResult(Nimbus.java:4092)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Processor$getLeader.getResult(Nimbus.java:4071)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:38)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin$SimpleWrapProcessor.process(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:162)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:518)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   org.apache.storm.thrift.server.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:18)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_201]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_201]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]

Comment: Is Nimbus running on the machine you're running the `storm list` command on? Check whether Nimbus is running properly by looking in the logs/nimbus.log file. Also how is the `%nimbus%` variable being replaced?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. Yes, i running the command in same machine. I check the logs and found one error - added in question. I check the variable when starting the nimbus, but this not changed... in the version 1.0.0 the same happens

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the list command slightly wrong. It should be `storm list -c nimbus.seeds='[\"localhost\"]'`. It needs to be the same as it would be in storm.yaml once the terminal interpreter is done with the string. So using `nimbus.seeds='[\"localhost\"]` ends up passing a string like `nimbus.seeds=["localhost"]` to Storm.